# Using member function to solve equation C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am currently trying to create a program to calculate the mass of a rocket with given time values by passing an array to a member function of a class. I get these two errors and can't seem to figure out how to get rid of them. Any suggestions are much appreciated, thank you.

23  8   [Error] prototype for 'double equip::calcmass(double)' does not match any in class 'equip'

13  10  [Error] candidate is: double equip::calcmass()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class equip
{
    public:
        double mass[999999999], velocity, height, time[999999999];
        double calcmass();
    private:
        double T = 7000;
        double g = 32.2;
        double K = 0.008;
};

double equip::calcmass(double time)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i=999999999; i++)
    {
        return mass[i] = (3000 - 40 * time[i]) / g;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    equip rocket;
    ifstream infile;
    string filename;
    cout<<"Enter input file name for time (time): ";
    cin>>filename;
    infile.open(filename.c_str());

    while(infile.fail())
    {
        cerr<<"Error opening file. \n";
        cout<<"Enter file name: ";
        cin>>filename;
        infile.open(filename.c_str());
    }

    for(i=0; i<999999999; i++)
    {
        infile>>rocket.time[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<999999999; i++)
    {
        cout<<rocket.mass[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use magic numbers. Name them properly to make it easier to read. Also, those big arrays (999999999) may smash the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class definition you've declared

```
double calcmass()
```

In the definition of the member function it's

```
double calcmass(double time)
```

They do not match. One takes a `double` as argument and the other does not.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a bunch of headers, and in the function declaration was missing the parameter presents in the function definition:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class equip
{
public:
    ...
    double calcmass(double time); // here was missing the parameter
    ...
};

double equip::calcmass(double time)
{
   ...
}
```

Also you are doing `time[i]` on `time` which is a `double`, so you can't use `operator[]`... If you want to pass an array, you can use `pointer to double`:

```
class equip{ 
    ...
    double calcmass(double* time)
}
double equip::calcmass(double* time)
{
   ...
}
```